# Problem with unittest mock and object from another module

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I'm currently developing some code in our repository which goes thru test and sonarqube. Said code connects to a postgres database but in the test instance doesn't connect, problem that from other teams was solved with mocking.

So I'm trying to mock the following code:

```
from app.commons.libpsycopg2 import Database

def extract(self, **kwargs) -> Union[dict, None]:

    # 1. Checking for cursor ------------------------------------------------
    with Database() as database:
        db_is_empty = database.is_empty(self.Const.SQL.schema, self.Const.SQL.table_name)
    if not db_is_empty:
        self.last_cursor = self._get_api_cursor()
        if not self.last_cursor:
            self.logger.warning(
                'table is not empty but cursor not found. Data will be overwrited'
            )
            position = self.Const.initial_position
        else:
            cur_dt, cur_tk = self._read_cursor_info(self.last_cursor)
            self.logger.info(
                f"Cursor found. date: {cur_dt.ctime()}, next ticket: {cur_tk}"
            )
            position = None
    else:
        position = self.Const.initial_position
```

And my test.py code goes like this:

```
from app.plugins.instance import Program
from unittest import mock

class Database:
    def _enter_(self):
        return self

    def _exit_(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        pass

    def is_empty(self, schema, table_name):
        return True


def test():
    instance = Program()
    with mock.patch('app.commons.libpsycopg2.Database', Database):
        extract = instance.extract()
```

Problem is that when I run the test.py script, the error goes like this:

```
In [4]: test()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 1
----> 1 test()

   1268 with mock.patch('app.commons.libpsycopg2.Database', Database):
-> 1269     extract = instance.extract()

    171 def extract(self, **kwargs) -> Union[dict, None]:
    172
    173     # 1. Checking for cursor ------------------------------------------------
    174     with Database() as database:
--> 175         db_is_empty = database.is_empty(self.Const.SQL.schema, self.Const.SQL.table_name)
    176     if not db_is_empty:
    177         self.last_cursor = self._get_api_cursor()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_empty'
```

Thing is I can't seem to mock the Database() instance in any way causing that every time is called, returns NoneType and breaks the script. I've tried several ways but don't seem to find a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to mock Database in the file which contains the class Program definition, and not in `app.commons.libpsycopg2`. So use the command:                                                       `with mock.patch('app.plugins.instance.Program.Database')`